# Multiple Tag Groups/Sets for separate channels

Tags: categories, tags

I have two separate channel types, let's say "News" and "Reviews" and each of those can have tags.

Is it possible to have separate tags for each of those? So News has it's own set of tags, that can't be selected when creating a new Review.

I'm coming from a Wordpress background, and in Wordpress these custom post types would have their own taxonomies. (Or News would use tags, and I would create a new one for Reviews).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like two different relation fields - linked with two different categories - would fit much better for your needs. When you create Tags/Taggroups everybody can insert everything so you can't forbid equal tags unless you hook into an event with php to prevent the saving process. When you create two different tag fields their autocomplete sources will be different but you can insert whatever you want.

So what you want to do is: create 2 different categories: The first `News` the second `Reviews` and add your keywords there. Then you create two relation fields, one linked with `News`, the other one linked with `Reviews`. Then you add those to your field layout

Comment: Ah I only just noticed the settings > tags > new group section on the admin ui. That works great, thanks!

Comment: But that does not prevent users from inserting equal tags in both fields